# How to prevent asset compilation for certain assets folders in Rails 7 engine that uses sprockets-rails with the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-sprockets

I am self hosting Tinymce in a Rails 7 engine that uses sprockets_rails

I have downloaded the tinymce code from the tinymce website and added to an `app/assets/tinymce` folder in the engine

I have the following manifest entry

```
//= link_tree ../javascripts/tinymce
```

This has the effect of ensuring that when the application using the engine is deployed to production all the tinymce assets are deployed too, however tinymce itself does not use fingerprinted asset links and is unable to find the compiled assets. I therefore need uncompiled assets in production but only for the tinymce assets

Obviously using

```
//= link ../javascripts/tinymce
```

in the manifest will not compile the subfolders, which is great but results in the subfolders not being deployed

How can I achieve this please?

The tinymce folder has many subfolders containing many css and javascript files all of which need to be ignored when compiling assets as part of the production deployment

So I need the assets in an uncompiled format without fingerprints

There is a tinymce rails gem that handles tinymce assets in the asset pipeline that I have been trying out, however, I am wondering if there is a better alternative?
The tinymce docs do not help with this.
I do not wish to use the cloud hosted solution as the overhead in time taken loading tinymce is unacceptable to me.

Bearing in mind that this code is in an engine and not the host application, writing code in a deployment script to copy assets is not an option.

What is the best way to achieve this please?

Comment: shouldn't you be using an npm package for that and just load `tinymce.js` which doesn't have any references to any other file.

Comment: Hmm! Thankyou, I'll take a look at those options